# Macbook Taps not working on site, but Clicks do?

Tags: html, flash, click, slider

Not necessarily my own website, but if you browse to NBA.com and take a look at the scores/schedules area that has the left/right slider, is there a reason taps that usually register as clicks don't cause the slider to move? Is it a flash bug? Just want to know out of curiosity's sake.

I'm on Google Chrome, OSX Lion, MacbookPro 13".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked which mouse events are called when using tap-to-click, and the behavior is the same as with "regular" clicks - which one would expect. This means there is no bug in Flash, nor in the way that events are passed on from Mac OS X.

So I've decompiled the SWF and found the reason:

The buttons (ActionScript2) have `onPress()` handlers, which each call a slider function (`scrollUnitContainer()`) at an interval of 50ms, using `setInterval()`. The `onRelease()` handler then clears the interval again. Both handlers are correctly called, regardless of whether you use tap-to-click or a mouse button.

`setInterval()`, however, does not call the specified function until the first time the interval has completed.  Since the time between the MOUSE_DOWN and CLICK events when using tap-to-click is less than 50ms, `scrollUnitContainer()` is never executed; when you use the actual click of the trackpad (or a mouse button), the time between MOUSE_DOWN and CLICK is long enough for the function to be called once.

To fix this, the author should simply add `scrollUnitContainer();` prior to setting the interval - then everything would work fine in all cases.

Comment: You *do* have a habit of exploring the unknown, man. My goodness! :)